# Losing all formatting when using Layout = null?

Tags: c#, html, css, model-view-controller, formatting

I am pulling out my hair trying to figure out what is going on here. I have a view with some very simple html/css code:

```
@model MyViewmodel
@{
    Layout = null;

}
<html>

<body>  
@if (ViewBag.LabelSize == "Small")
        {

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h6><b>Owner</b>: @Model.ownerLabel</h6>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h6><b>Model</b>: @Model.modelNum</h6>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(@Model.BarcodeImage)" />

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h6><b>Serial</b>: @Model.serialNum</h6>
                    <h6><b>Project</b>: @Model.project</h6>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10"></div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <h6><b>Recieved</b>: @Model.newDate</h6>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-10"></div>

            </div>


        }
  </body>
</html>
```

I am creating a "printable" page for a barcode label. The page just needs to be completely white except for the label details. So that is my reason for Layout = null.

My problem is that when I set the layout to null, it display my model data, but it ignores my div tags and columns. I even checked in debug mode, it literally skips the row and container tags, all while hitting the Model information. If I delete the layout = null, and just use my regular layout, it organizes my data exactly how i want. What is going on here? I thought the if statement was causing it, but apparently not.

Does setting the Layout = null; completely remove even the views formatting?

Comment: It looks like you're missing a link to your css

Comment: Thanks @SteveCzetty , simple fix I overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Layout page holds all of your css references, your content page will only have css if you reference the layout page.